# How widely spread is the expression "make a parking lot of sth"?

Tags: expressions

In [this Quora article](https://www.quora.com/Are-the-Swedes-despised-by-others/all_comments/Krister-Sundelin?__nsrc__=4&__snid3__=13944903565&comment_id=170276197&comment_type=2), someone said the following.

> ...but I have no memory of it because of an abundance of ale. I think we also solved world poverty, and it somehow involved *making a parking lot of most of the Middle-East and London*.

I asked what it meant and this is the explanation I've got (a good one, I love the wording).

> ...everyone considers every rock most holy to their particular group. So if you just flatten out everything and make it as non-holy as possible – i.e. a parking lot – it’s not holy to anyone anymore, nobody has any reason to fight...

I'd like to start using that expression but I can't judge how widely spread it is or, at least, how easy to figure out the message would be. I had to ask, so it's not obvious. On the other hand, I might be too slow to get it, making me not representative for a general case.

Comment: Seeing as the speaker is Swedish, I suggest that this metaphor derives from their native country.  I am not familiar with "making something into a parking lot" ( BrEng: *car park*) or  "make a parking lot of something"

Comment: I've heard the expression. It means to level a place, to raze it, to destroy everything there. Why do you want to say that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Being an almost native speaker of Swedish, I assure you that expression doesn't come from the Viking tongue. :)

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I don't want to say **that**. I would be using it while referring to eliminating the infectious connotations often raised while discussing politics and/or religion. The sense you've suggested, I have rather limited use for.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I believe the expression will carry those connotations, whether you intend them or not.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Oh, I see where I failed. I misread your comment and got it to be *I've heard that the expression means to...*, inferring lack of certainty in your statement. Now, I see that you actually claim that expression to mean *leveling to the ground*. I won't use it as intended (although I may in a more appropriate situation). Also, I'd suggest that you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expression means to level a place, to raze it, to destroy everything there.
You could conceivably use it in another sense, but it will have that connotation.

There's a Joni Mitchell song, "Big Yellow Taxi" with the line "they paved paradise...and put up a parking lot."

Comment: Agreed. This Ngram shows that "put up a parking lot" is much more widely used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+a+parking+lot+of%2C+put+up+a+parking+lot&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20parking%20lot%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20up%20a%20parking%20lot%3B%2Cc0